# Proxy setings for web service(client or service hosted server)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add the a web service through Web reference, i am able to find the service while trying to add it, not able to add, the option is disabled. I suspect this is because of the proxy settings, What do you suggest? While mentioning he proxy in the the client application which proxy should i mention,the proxy of my machine in which client application is hosted which is consuming the web service or the proxy of the machine in which the web service is hosted?

Answer (score 0):

If the client machine is accessing the Internet (and therefore web service) through a proxy server, then the client application needs to know about those proxy settings.

Comment: yes Anders, I tried giving the proxy of the client machine in client application, still having problem. What if the server which web service is hosted is having proxy settings? do we need to mention it somewhere in the client application inorder to bypass that proxy also?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to do that. Are you able to access the web service from the client machine using a web browser? Is the server behind a firewall?

Comment: Yes, I am able to browse the service from client machine, and the hosted server is having firewall enabled.

Comment: I saw a similar question on another forum where a user was having the same problem (the Add Web Reference button was disabled) and the solution seemed to be to setup proxy settings in the Visual Studio configuration file, detailed in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910804.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved after 2 months. I was busy with some other items so couldn't work on this. Now that I solve through a simple technique. I hosted the web sevice in the local environment and added the web reference. Then i hosted the same web service in the web server which is in different environment and network. and i took the URL of it and replaced in the class file of Web service which got created  previously while i tried adding web reference from local environment.